# Autoellipsis not working on content which is faded in

Tags: jquery, ellipsis

I am using the following jQuery plugin :

http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/

The ellipsis plugin works fine on the selectors I choose when the page loads. When I load another section into the site using fadeIn and fadeOut the new content which is faded in doesn't seem to have the ellipsis.

I had a look at using the "live" option for the ellipsis but haven't had any luck.

Any help on this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin will only work on elements which are available in the DOM when the page loads. I assume therefore that you are loading new content dynamically, via AJAX?

In which case, just before you call `fadeIn()` you will need to call `$("#mySelector").ellipsis()` again so that it can process the new content.

Comment: I placed $("#mySelector").ellipsis() just before the fadeIn it didn't seem to work, but placing it after the fadeIn seemed to work a treat. Thank you :)